# Remove Options from Bootstrap-Select when Proceeding Select Changes

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-select

I have tried multiple combinations and just can't clear this control.
I am using jquery 3.2.1, the control is Bootstrap-select v1.13.1 here is the link
https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/.

I want to clear the teamPositionFilter options which is multi-select whenever the 
groupFilter before it changes. Right now it is appending values after each change. I can step through the javascript code but it does not change the list.

```
@Html.DropDownList("groupFilter", (SelectList)(@ViewBag.GroupList), new { @class = "singleselectpicker col-md-3", title = "Group:", data_header = "Select Group:" })
@Html.DropDownList("teamPositionFilter", (MultiSelectList)(@ViewBag.TeamPositionList), new { @class = "multiselectpicker col-md-3", multiple = "multiple", title = "Team Position:", data_header = "Select one or more Team Positions:" })

$(function() {

$('#groupFilter').change(function () {
    var #teamPositionFilter = $('#teamPositionFilter');
    #teamPositionFilter.find('option').remove();
    #teamPositionFilter.selectpicker('refresh');
});


$('.singleselectpicker').selectpicker({
    showTick: true,
    tickIcon: 'glyphicon-pushpin',
    liveSearch: true,
    liveSearchStyle: 'contains',
    selectOnTab: true,
    showContent: true,
    size: 10,
    width: 'false'
});

$('.multiselectpicker').selectpicker({
        actionsBox: true,
        selectAllText: 'Select All',
        deselectAllText: 'Deselect All',
        selectedTextFormat: 'count',
        showTick: true,
        tickIcon: 'glyphicon-pushpin',
        liveSearch: true,
        liveSearchStyle: 'contains',
        selectOnTab: true,
        showContent: true,
        size: 10,
        width: 'false',
        multipleSeparator: ', '
});
```

});

Answer (score 9):

There is an old issue listed [here](https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/52)

To delete the selected item:

```
var itemSelectorOption = $('#select-id option:selected');
itemSelectorOption.remove(); 
$('#select-id').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Answer (score 7):

This statement worked fine for the Single List:

```
    var groupFilter = $('#groupFilter');
    groupFilter.selectpicker('val', '');
    groupFilter.find('option').remove();
    groupFilter.selectpicker("refresh");
```

But I had to also from the

from the multiselect list.

```
    var teamPositionFilter = $('#teamPositionFilter');
    teamPositionFilter.selectpicker('deselectAll');
    teamPositionFilter.find('option').remove();
    teamPositionFilter.find('li').remove();
    teamPositionFilter.selectpicker('refresh');
```